# Dragging Object Between java windows inside java and other delphi panel

Tags: java, delphi, events, awt

I have a Java AWT window inside of a Delphi panel (I know it's bad, but it's part of a large project that I can't change).

I want to drag an object from the Java AWT window to another Delphi panel (other than the one the AWT window is in).

Unfortunately, while dragging the object outside of the Java window, the focus stays on it (I guess the focus lasts as long as the mouse-dragging-event occurs).

Is there anyway to convert the mouse-dragging event of the Java window to the mouse-dragging event of the other Delphi panel while the mouse is being clicked?

Here is an image that shows how the window looks.

[image]

Comment: The only way you can drag objects out of the Java window into a Delphi window is if 1) the Java code implements the Win32 `IDataObject` and `IDragSource` interfaces and uses the Win32 `DoDragDrop()` function to handle the drag&drop operation, and 2) if your Delphi code implements the Win32 `IDropTarget` interface and calls the Win32 `RegisterDragDrop()` function to register interest in receiving dragged objects from outside your app.

Comment: Start with [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html), this allows you to transfer data (around, into and out of your program)

Comment: Also see [Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: The key to your export problem, is generating a `DataFlavor` and a format of the data which Delphi will understand